# Numpy mask in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

What is the easiest way to save elements from a list using `np.where` or similar?

A short example:

```
l1 = [-144.92170726320364, 697.7739312692029, -2.0, -2.0]
```

I want to keep the elements which are different from -2.0. I tried:

```
l2 = [l1[index] for index in len(l1) if l1[index] != -2.0]
```

As well as:

```
l3 = np.where(l1 != -2.0)
```

In first case I received error. In the second case I obtained `(array([0]),)`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal Python array

```
l2 = [i for i in l1 if i!=-2.0]
```

Numpy array

```
l1 = np.array(l1)
l2 = l1[l1 != -2.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you change your `list` into a `numpy.array`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l1 = np.array([-144.92170726320364, 697.7739312692029, -2.0, -2.0])
```

you can do the comparison against the scalar

```
>>> l1 != -2.0
array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then use that expression to index into your original array

```
>>> l1[l1 != -2.0]
array([-144.92170726,  697.77393127])
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
[l for l in l1 if l != -2.0]
```